# Changing summary statistics terms in esttab

Tags: statistics, stata, summary

I am using the following code:

```
estpost summarize gdpgrowth, listwise
esttab, cells("mean sd  min max") nomtitle number
```

The idea is to create a summary statistics table of the variable `gdpgrowth` using `esttab`.

I get this output:

[image]

I like everything about this except I would want to take away the `(1)` from the mean name, turn `sd` to `standard deviation`, turn `min` into `minimum` and `max` into `maximum`.

I would also like to round off each number to the second decimal and change `N` to `sample size`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
sysuse auto, clear

eststo clear
estpost summarize price

esttab, cells("mean(fmt(%8.2f)) sd(fmt(%8.2f)) min(fmt(%8.2f)) max(fmt(%8.2f))") ///
stats(N, fmt(%5.0f) labels("Sample size")) nonumbers wide ///
collabels("Mean" "Std. Dev." "Minimum" "Maximum")

----------------------------------------------------------------

                     Mean    Std. Dev.      Minimum      Maximum
----------------------------------------------------------------
price             6165.26      2949.50      3291.00     15906.00
----------------------------------------------------------------
Sample size            74                                       
----------------------------------------------------------------
```